# Flutter - change current platform on unit test

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, flutter-platform-channel

I'm currently making unit tests for my app, and have a problem to test functions from packages made only for android & iOS (https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_text_recognition).

I have a code which works when I use it on real device, but don't works in my unit test with the error : "MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method vision#startTextRecognizer on channel google_mlkit_text_recognizer)".

As I understand, the problem is that the package methods won't work on another platform than android / iOS.
Is there a way to set platform to iOS during unit tests ?
Already tried to modify the "defaultTargetPlatform", doesn't work.

Thanks,
Julien

Created a unit test calling google_mlkit_text_recognition functions, which work on device, but not on unit tests.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```dart
debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.iOS;
```